# Enumerate and itemize undefined + captions not working

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, errors

I am trying to recompile a document in kwrite; I previously compiled it all OK under debian squeeze about 6 months ago, but I now have an opensuse 11.2 (kwrite-4.3.5-0.1.1.x86_64).

A few problems have cropped up in the recompile
1) \begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate} are undefined
2) \begin{itemize}...\end{itemize} are also undefined
3) all my captions now lead to undefined control errors

Example output:

```
1)

! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after 
                                 \endlist \enit@toks \expandafter {\enit@sav...
l.163 \end{enumerate}

2)
[9]
! Undefined control sequence.
\enit@enditemize ->\enit@after 
                               \endlist \enit@toks \expandafter {\enit@savek...

3)
! Undefined control sequence.
\captiontextfont@default ->\cpb@font 

l.144 ...d compositions as estimated by weighing.}
```

Any advice?

Also, the captcha on this site is really broken. disabling javascript just throws a (framed) content-length required error and shows a google page (WTF?) Secondly, I had to enter it in 4 times (after enabling javascript) because (I didn't have tags, I had invalid tags, I had a bad captcha (unreadable) and then I got a good one); Is there somewhere I can report this?

Edit:

- Could not report bug. Would not let me post my question "your openID (?) is incorrect", but there was no field (even with javascript) to enter this. ???
- Here is the minimal example that was asked for in the discussion (Am I meant to just keep editing my posts??)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{thesis}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paralist} %fancy list of figures

\title{A b C d e f g}

\author{me}\vspace{4ex}
\date{2010}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} \hspace{1pt} \pagebreak


\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\vspace{1ex}
Stuff.

\end{abstract}

\cleardoublepage

{

\cleardoublepage
\mbox{}
\cleardoublepage

%back to 1,2,3 style numbering
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{itemize}
 \item One
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Caption minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{thesis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\title{asdf}
\author{me}\vspace{4ex}

\date{2010}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Lalalla
\end{abstract}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.95 \textwidth]{test.png}
\caption{Caption test}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
  ! Undefined control sequence. \captionlabelfont@default ->\cph@font l.19 \caption{Caption test} ! Undefined control sequence. \captionlabelfont@default ->\cph@font l.19 \caption{Caption test} ! Undefined control sequence. \captiontextfont@default ->\cpb@font l.19 \caption{Caption test} ! Undefined control sequence. \captionlabelfont@default ->\cph@font l.19 \caption{Caption test} ! Undefined control sequence. \captionlabelfont@default ->\cph@font l.19 \caption{Caption test} ! Undefined control sequence. \captiontextfont@default ->\cpb@font l.19 \caption{Caption test} 
[2 ] (./test.aux) ) (see the transcript file for additional information) Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 471338 bytes). Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: You can report your issues with the site on [meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For the TeX question, please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Try to load `paralist` before `enumitem`.

Comment: OK, that fixes the itemize problem, thanks a lot -- I would have not have thought to do that. 

I was under the impression each package is relatively non-interacting, so usepackage order is not super-critical.


Can someone explain this black magic? I don't understand what is going on behind the scenes, and why this fixes it.

Also, I will try to narrow down the caption problem.

Comment: Well both packages (enumitem and paralist) redefines the standard list environments. So using both packages in a document is certainly "dangerous".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your caption problem. I don't get any error. I would suspect that your caption.sty is too old.

I have caption.sty    2010/01/09 v3.1m Customizing captions (AR)

Comment: Brilliant!

I downloaded  http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption.zip, compiled the .ins files (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX) then replaced my *caption*.sty files (after backing up).. All working now. 

Cool, thaks all! (Now to do some Work!)

Comment: Yes, once upon a time there was a too naive implemented way of detecting the `thesis` document class offered by CTAN. For details (and a picture of my cat) see http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=14674#p55018 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106201/using-caption-package-with-thesis-class-undefined-control-sequence

Answer (score 0):

OK, So for anyone out there; the UWA style file `thesis` is broken with my version of caption. Similar problems have been reported with upgrades to caption breaking university style files.

I have no ability to edit custom style files, I just use them.

As a work around, as suggested at http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/problem-with-caption-in-Mactex-2009-td3988716.html#a3989331 (or http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2009-November/041847.html), is to use `ccaption`, instead of `caption`. The result is different (and less nice looking), but it works.

Unfortunately, the caption file does not seem to be clearly version stamped, or a dependency is causing the problem, as the last marked change is in 2008, which was long enough ago, and my other system was up-to-date to make me suspicious.

So the only info I have is the non-working `caption.sty` file has:

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{caption}[2008/04/01 v3.1h Customizing captions (AR)]
$ md5sum ./texmf/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
677bc2647b4de7942f16e897e1eadab2  ./texmf/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty

Thanks to everyone for the help.

Hope this helps.

P.s. For a latex site, a software package that is usually associated with anti-wysiwig fuddy duddies, there sure is a lot of scripting going on here -- I can't even post without it.